# How to fix strange prediction results in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have a simple example in scikit-learn for prediction. Here is my data file (data.csv):

```
first second third target1 target2
 800   400    240    400     25
 400   200    120    200     50
 200   100    60     100     100
 100   50     30     50      200
 50    25     15     25      400
```

The **features** include : first ,second and third

The **targets** include : target1 and target2

Now I want to provide new values for the features and predict target1 and target2. As you can see, there is a trend between the values of features and the values of the target1 and target2:

**By doubling the features values the value of target1 also doubles while the value of target2 cuts in half**

For example if I provide the values : 1600 , 800 and 480 for the first, second and the third features, I expect to get 800 and **12.5** for the target1 and target2 respectively. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from collections import *
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

features = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

features.head()
features_name = ['first' , 'second' , 'third']
target_name = ['target1','target2']

X = features[features_name]
y = features[target_name]

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.155, random_state = 42)

linear_regression_model = LinearRegression()
linear_regression_model.fit(X_train,y_train)

new_data  = OrderedDict([('first',1600) ,('second',800),('third',480) ])
new_data = pd.Series(new_data).values.reshape(1,-1)
ss = linear_regression_model.predict(new_data)

print (ss)
```

Here is the output:

```
[[ 800.         -284.58549223]]
```

As you can see the predicted value for the target1 is exactly what is expected **while the predicted value for the target2 (-284.58) is far away from what is expected (12.5)**

Does anybody know what is wrong here and how I can fix this issue? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `random-forest`(tag removed & replaced with `linear-regression`).

Answer (score 2):

Edit: there is no linear correlation between your inputs (any of them, they are essentially all the same) and your target2. It seems to be an exponential decay. Try transforming your feature to another feature (1/exp(x)) and then you can do a linear regression on that feature

Edit2: my mistake, it is simply 1/x

Also.. (original post below)
I'm not an expert, but it appears that your input features are not only highly correlated, they are actually perfectly correlated (linear correlation that is) - this generally makes regression breaks.
The intuitive reason is that because they are correlated, there exists an infinite amount of possible coefficients, where they counter one another, and the prediction would still be exactly the same (imagine in your case first-second is exactly the same as 2first-3second or 0first-1second etc).
I also think this causes the normal equation of linear regression to generate a matrix that cannot be inverted..

Comment: Thanks for your response. However it is not clear to me when you say " exponential decay" because it is not an exponential decay for sure. When I say "strange prediction" I mean the prediction for target1 is absolutely correct while target2 is NOT. Both target1 and target2 have the similar trend (although inverse) and it is kind of weird. Can you manipulate the above example code to get correct predictions for both targets?

Comment: I made a mistake in my initial post, it is simply 1/x.
I tried implementing the correction but I have no experience with linear regression that generates 2 outputs, so I instead created 2 regression separately (code below) using only first as input (because second and third are not necessary)

`lr_1 = LinearRegression()`  
`lr_1.fit(X['first'],y['target1'])`
`lr_2 = LinearRegression()`
`lr_2.fit(np.vectorize(lambda x: 1/x)(X['first']),y['target2']`
note that it is crucial to transform input for prediction as well:
`lr_2.predict(1/1600)`

you'll have to modify shapes and types here